# Python | I need help for my class (Changing from binary to decimal)

Tags: python, binary, decimal

I need help changing from binary to decimal for class, this is what I have if someone could help me fix what i may have wrong, (note this is sort of the format I have to turn it in, without other functions) what do i have wrong?

```
x = str (input("Enter Binario: "))
c = len (x)
decimal = 0
b ="" 
for y in (b):
    if ( b == "1"):
        b = 1
    else :
        if (b =="0"):
            b =0
    z = c - 1
    t = (2**z) * x
    decimal = decimal + t 
print (decimal)
```

Comment: For one thing, you set `b` to `""`, then you try to iterate over it.  Since it is empty, the loop will exit immediately.  Perhaps it would make more sense to iterate over `x` rather than `b`.

Comment: Inside the loop, you are looking at `b`.  You want to look at `y` (once you change it to iterate over `x`).

Comment: And inside the loop, you are setting `b` to `0` or `1`, then discarding it.  Why not choose a new variable name for it, then use it to construct your result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you are just learning, but take a careful look at your code and you should see a lot of simple mistakes.

```
x = str (input("Enter Binario: "))  # You store the input a x, ok.
c = len (x) # You store the length of x as c, ok.
decimal = 0
b = "" # You initialize b to an empty string 
for y in (b): # Then try to iterate over it - this will never loop
    if ( b == "1"):
        b = 1
    else :
        if (b =="0"):
            b =0
    z = c - 1
    t = (2**z) * x
    decimal = decimal + t 
print (decimal)
```

So let's fix the first issue.

```
x = str (input("Enter Binario: "))  # You store the input a x, ok.
c = len (x) # You store the length of x as c, ok.
decimal = 0
b = "" # You initialize b to an empty string 
for y in x: # You iterate the characters of x, ok.
    if ( b == "1"): # You check the value of b, where you should be checking the value of y
        b = 1
    else :
        if (b =="0"):
            b =0
    z = c - 1
    t = (2**z) * x
    decimal = decimal + t 
print (decimal)
```

So let's fix that

```
x = str (input("Enter Binario: "))  # You store the input a x, ok.
c = len (x) # You store the length of x as c, ok.
decimal = 0
b = "" # You initialize b to an empty string 
for y in x: # You iterate the characters of x, ok.
    if y == "1": # You check the value of y, ok
        b = 1 # and assign to b, but below you use x in your equation
    else :
        if (b =="0"):
            b =0
    z = c - 1
    t = (2**z) * x
    decimal = decimal + t 
print (decimal)
```

So let's fix that

```
x = str (input("Enter Binario: "))  # You store the input a x, ok.
c = len (x) # You store the length of x as c, ok.
decimal = 0
b = "" # You initialize b to an empty string 
for y in x: # You iterate the characters of x, ok.
    if y == "1": # You check the value of y, ok
        x = 1 # and assign to x, ok
    else:
        x = 0
    z = c - 1 # You are trying to get the position of the current character here so you can raise to the appropriate power, but this value will be the same each time.  Instead, modify what c is.
    t = (2**z) * x
    decimal = decimal + t 
print (decimal)
```

So let's fix that

```
x = str (input("Enter Binario: "))  # You store the input a x, ok.
c = len (x) # You store the length of x as c, ok.
decimal = 0
b = "" # You initialize b to an empty string 
for y in x: # You iterate the characters of x, ok.
    if y == "1": # You check the value of y, ok
        x = 1 # and assign to x, ok
    else:
        x = 0
    c = c - 1 # You decrement c (the original length of y), ok
    t = (2**c) * x
    decimal = decimal + t 
print (decimal)
```

Now it works!

A few more things to note.  Until you become very proficient in reading / writing Python, don't use single character, meaningless names.  The above solution reads much better as

```
binary_string = input("Enter Binario: ")
binary_string_size = len(binary_string)

decimal = 0

for character in binary_string: 
    if character == "1":
        bit = 1
    else:
        bit = 0
    binary_string_size -= 1
    t = (2**c) * x
    decimal = decimal + (2**binary_string_size) * bit
print(decimal)
```

Later, when you are more comfortable in the language, see that this does the same thing (and even does some simple input validation)

```
binary_string = input("Enter Binario: ")

if not set(binary_string).issubset({'1', '0'}):
    raise Exception("Binary string can only contain 1's and 0's")

decimal = 0

for exponent, character in enumerate(binary_string[::-1]):
    if character == "1":
        decimal += 2**exponent

print (decimal)
```

And later still, you might want to use a list comprehension

```
binary_string = input("Enter Binario: ")

if not set(binary_string).issubset({'1', '0'}):
    raise Exception("Binary string can only contain 1's and 0's")

decimal = sum([(2**exponent) * int(char) for exponent, char in enumerate(binary_string[::-1])])
```